# Could we reopen this post

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/how-to-configure-mx-records-and-a-records-to-point-a-domain-to-google-apps) has revised their statement into a question - could we reopen, it's actually quite a useful answer...

Answer (score 1):

Asking for clarification and will reopen + revise question upon receiving further information from asker (providing this question is not a duplicate).